# User defined calculation on structs/classes

Tags: c++, class, math, unity-game-engine, struct

I was once using Unity and they use a cool System to add and multiply vectors.
This is a short excerpt from the Reference (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html)

```
foreach (Transform child in transform) {
   child.position += Vector3.up * 10.0F;
}
```

as you can see they can just add and multiply two Vectors (structs/classes) even though they could have different variables. Right now when I try to make such a calculation I have to add the x and y of a 2d float vector individually. 
So how can i add structs like a

```
struct Vec2f{
   float x;
   float y;
};
```

together by writing

```
Vec2f c = a + b;
```

instead of

```
c.x = a.x + b.x;
c.y = a.y + b.y;
```

Comment: If you're a beginner note that you're possibly also looking for Extensions, which are a totally key thing in c# and Unity.  For example, in answer this simple question ... http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/1118868/view.html ... it gives an excellent pedagogic tutorial on extensions.  I urge you to familiarize yourself with them, and use them everywhere.  Enjoy!

Comment: Here's another good example which relates to Vectors more as you ask. http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/1114273/view.html  Go for it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

You need to overload operators like '+', '-' etc. in your struct. Example for addition:

```
struct Vec2f
{
    float x;
    float y;

    Vec2f operator+(const Vec2f& other) const
    {
        Vec2f result;
        result.x = x + other.x;
        result.y = y + other.y;
        return result;
    }
};
```

EDIT 2:
RIJIK asks in comment:

> Also i wonder if there are some tricks to make the functions not to be so repetetive. I mean if i now want to use an operator i have to make a function for each operator even if there is no big difference between the functions besides the operator which is used. How do you approach in implementing calculations or many operators?

So one thing you can do is use another operators in operator. Something like you can change subtraction to addition, by simply negate second number:

a - b becomes a + (-b)

Of course you need negation operator first in your struct to do that. Example code:

```
struct Vec2f
{
    float x;
    float y;

    Vec2f operator+(const Vec2f& other) const
    {
        Vec2f result;
        result.x = x + other.x;
        result.y = y + other.y;
        return result;
    }

    Vec2f operator-() const
    {
        Vec2f result;
        result.x = -x;
        result.y = -y;
        return result;
    }

    // we use two operators from above to define this
    Vec2f operator-(const Vec2f& other) const
    {
        return (*this + (-other));
    }
};
```

One nice thing about this is that if you change addition for example than you don't need to change subtraction. It is changed automatically.

And as reply to this:

> But i don't understand why i should make the functions constant.

Because then you can use this function with constant variables. For example:

```
const Vec2f screenSize = { 800.0f, 600.0f };
const Vec2f boxSize = { 100.0f, 200.0f };
const Vec2f sub = screenSize - boxSize;
```

I am using here also curly braces initialization, cause you don't define any constructor.

Comment: Don't forget about the non-member overload option as well.

Comment: This is more elegant way for me, than doing this in global space.

Comment: Ideally you should make the parameter *const ref* or (for such a small struct) passing a copy may well be faster. Also the whole function should be const.

Comment: Yeah i have looked into it a bit and now placed a const behind the type in the parameter list. But i don't understand why i should make the functions constant. Also i wonder if there are some tricks to make the functions not to be so repetetive. I mean if i now want to use an operator i have to make a function for each operator even if there is no big difference between the functions besides the operator which is used. How do you approach in implementing calculations or many operators?

Comment: I edited that now its constant. With this you can also use constant variables in your code.

Comment: You can make subtraction as adding opposite value, i mean something like: r=this+(-other). Of course you need first to define minus operator.

Comment: Thanks for answering my questions and extending your answer!